# в jquery метод hide не принимает параметры

Tags: jquery, hide

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
        <title>Курс по Javascript</title>
        <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Общий div для всей в -->
        <div class="maindiv" id="main_div">
            <!-- Блок хедера (шапка сайта) -->
            <div id="forheader">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="900" height="108" alt="Хедер" title="Шапка сайта" />
            </div>
            <!-- Конец блока хедера -->
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Проблема наблюдается во всех браузерах. Метод `hide` работает, но не принимает параметр '3000', т.е. отобранная картинка прячется сразу, а не в течение 3 секунд. Та же проблема и с методом `show`. `fadeOut()` также не работает. В остальном все ок. Такое ощущение, что не работает все, что связано с плавностью. Извините, если что-то не досказал или какую-либо часть кода не прикрепил - начинаю программировать только.

Вот код файла скриптов:

```
$(function(){
    $('img[width=900]').hide(3000); 
});
```

Comment: вместо `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` подключил `<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Подключил более старую версию с файла, а именно jquery 3.0.0 и все заработало

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48778/discussion-on-question-by----jquery--hide---).